# How batch rename artboards in Adobe illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting, artboard

Is there a way to batch rename a bunch of selected artboards in illustrator?

any script or plug-in appreciated...

---

✅Answer
Uppdated 2024, feb:

Code by @GoodJobStudios
Edit by Me

In this edit, I added descriptions to make clear the start artboard and end artboard for range of artboards need to be renamed also defined the title and suffix - suffix is a text that could be place at the end, after the increment numbering.

Save as .JSX

```
      function artBoardName_serial() {
        var startArtboard = 1 //From this Artboard,
        var endArtboard = 10 //To this one (These are Artboards Index Number)
        var titlePf = "Artboards title here" //Prefix text (Can be empty like "")
// Numbering happens between the Title and Suffix.
        var titleSf = "Suffix text here" //Suffix text (Can be empty like "")
            var doc = app.activeDocument;
            var start=(startArtboard)-1;
             for (var i = start, l = doc.artboards.length; i < endArtboard; i++) {  
                if (doc.artboards[i].active) {
                        }
                        // THIS IS WHERE THE RENAMING HAPPENS
                        doc.artboards[i].name = titlePf+((i-start+1))+titleSf;  
                    }
            }
    
        function renameArtBoard_MAIN() {
            if (app.documents.length == 0) {  
        alert("No Open / Active Document Found");  
            } else {  
                artBoardName_serial();
            }  
        }
    
        renameArtBoard_MAIN();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works (save as .jsx in your script folder)

```
      function artBoardName_serial() {
        var doc = app.activeDocument;  
        for (var i = 0, l = doc.artboards.length; i < l; i++) {  
            if (doc.artboards[i].active) {
                    }
                    // THIS IS WHERE THE RENAMING HAPPENS
                    doc.artboards[i].name = "a"+(i+1);  
                }    
        }

    function renameArtBoard_MAIN() {
        if (app.documents.length == 0) {  
    alert("No Open / Active Document Found");  
        } else {  
            artBoardName_serial();
        }  
    }

    renameArtBoard_MAIN();
```

Comment: Great... Very handy. I have a wish list of artboards naming. Just to know : 1. Adding ability to keep current name. 2. Adding a prefix. 3. Adding a suffix 4. Changes applied to a range of artboards. 5. More numbering options like adding tab zeros and set a starting number manually. all of these comes so more cool with a good UI. :D... btw thanks for this.

Comment: Simple. No complicated configurations. Easy to change what its renaming.

Answer (score 3):

Building on GoodJobStudios's code from the accepted answer, this script will give the user find-and-replace prompts. Save as .jsx, open your Illustrator file, and run script from File -> Scripts -> Other Scripts -> Find and select the saved .jsx file.

Alternatively, if on MacOS, save the file to your Illustrator script presets [HDNAME]/Applications/Adobe Illustrator 2021/Presets.localized/en_US/Scripts/
to keep the file easily accessible until a new version of Illustrator is released.

```
  function artBoardName_serial() {
    var doc = app.activeDocument,
        searchtext = prompt("Artboard name substring to find:", ""),
        replacetext = prompt("Replace found text with:", "");
    if (searchtext == undefined || searchtext === "") {
      alert("Text to find cannot be blank.");
    } else {
      for (var i = 0, l = doc.artboards.length; i < l; i++) {
        doc.artboards[i].name = doc.artboards[i].name.replace(searchtext,replacetext);
      }
    }
  }

  function renameArtBoard_MAIN() {
    if (app.documents.length == 0) {
      alert("No Open / Active Document Found");
    } else {
      artBoardName_serial();
    }
  }
  renameArtBoard_MAIN();
```

Comment: Good script, it can save a lot of time!

Answer (score 1):

It is not currently possible to script this because its not possible to know which artboards are selected. There is no such hook in the scripting api*.  But its possible to change name just not based on selection.

It is possible that the plugin API has these functions, but given that only newest version o illustrator CC can even inteligently do this I doubut its well documented. Atleast in the current SDK there seems to be no mention of this. So given that thi sis the case and if we add the extra overhead of plugin development its not worth the time involved.

* This is what happens when the API is not a core design feature of your application, one can not really add a API it must be the first thing that is done every time something gets done.

Comment: So how Illustrator understands which ones have to be deleted! because multiselect and delete is available.

Comment: @RoozbehE Illustrator may know a lot of things but if they dont expose it with the API theres nothing we can do.

Comment: So... I thought may this give some people a clue here about issue ... I Returned to my thread 'cause I just needed the subject again. Found some PDF documents about artboard and artboards objects in jse. For sure you developers knew it before, but maybe comments here  pop somethin in who ever's head they read this! Who knows!

Comment: @RoozbehE But i can still batch rename them just not get the selection

Comment: really? you mean it's possible to batch rename all artboards... and put increment to it too... even this could be good for me!

Comment: @RoozbehE yes just not based on selection. So really there is no good way to define what order and which artboards. But if you want to rename them all then thats fine and its a bit convolved.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the answers here, specifically franklylately's, to allow for regexes like `Artboard \d+`.

Per usual, save the code as a `.jsx` file, then run the script in Illustrator via `File -> Scripts -> Other Scripts`.

```
function artBoardName_serial() {
  var doc = app.activeDocument;
  var searchText = prompt("Artboard name substring to find:", "");
  var replaceText = prompt("Replace found text with:", "");

  if (searchText === undefined || searchText === "") {
    alert("Text to find cannot be blank.");
  } else {
    for (var i = 0, l = doc.artboards.length; i < l; i++) {
      var searchRegex = new RegExp(searchText, "g");

      doc.artboards[i].name = doc.artboards[i].name.replace(searchRegex, replaceText);
    }
  }
}

function renameArtBoard_MAIN() {
  if (app.documents.length == 0) {
    alert("No Open / Active Document Found");
  } else {
    artBoardName_serial();
  }
}

renameArtBoard_MAIN();
```