# Is there a way to do a find/replace on artboard names?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, automation, artboard, illustrator-scripting

I've got a file with over 300 artboards.  Each artboard has a unique name e.g. "symbol.hot.surface".  I need to replace all the periods "." with an underline "_"

I'm pretty sure this can be done with a script, but that's beyond me.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: This may not answer your question but check out this similar question [How batch rename artboards in Adobe illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/104010/how-batch-rename-artboards-in-adobe-illustrator)

Answer (score 4):

Design Phoenix made an awesome script, I modified the script so that you get a prompt and enter in the values right in Illustrator

Script below:

```
#target illustrator
var doc = app.activeDocument;

jsfind = prompt("Find: ", "");
jsreplace = prompt("Replace: ", "");

for ( var i=0; i<doc.artboards.length ;i++) {
var aBoard = doc.artboards[i].active;
var oldName = doc.artboards[i].name;
doc.artboards[i].name = oldName.replace (jsfind, jsreplace);
}
```

Note, this script is case sensitive.

---

The script can easily be modified to work for layers instead of artboards. [`FindReplaceLayers.jsx`](https://github.com/WELZ-gh/Drafts/blob/master/Saved/Illustrator%20Scripting/FindReplaceLayers.jsx)

---

If you wanted to use REGEX while searching, just add the following line of code to the script:

```
var jsfindREGEX = new RegExp(jsfind,"g");
```

In this line replace `jsfind` with `regex`

```
oldName.replace (jsfindREGEX, jsreplace);
```

You can find both Regex script on Github.

[`FindReplaceArtboardsREGEX.jsx`](https://github.com/WELZ-gh/Drafts/blob/master/Saved/Illustrator%20Scripting/FindReplaceArtboardsREGEX.jsx)
[`FindReplaceLayersREGEX.jsx`](https://github.com/WELZ-gh/Drafts/blob/master/Saved/Illustrator%20Scripting/FindReplaceLayersREGEX.jsx)

---

And as GerardFalla nicely pointed out, you can also use the layers script in Photoshop which is very helpful.

Comment: Moreover that layers script will happily work in Photoshop too (at least on Win 10) though the artboard renamer won't. These are **excellent** resources - thank you!

Comment: That's good to know that it works in PS. It doesn't use keyboards which is why it won't work there.

Comment: I meant to say artboards, not keyboards.

Comment: Note that `oldName.replace(str1, str2)` will replace only the first occurence of `str1` and OP's `symbol.hot.surface` will become `symbol_hot.surface`. To replace all the occurences you need to use regex instead of a string: `oldName.replace(/\./g, str2)`

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy thanks for that, I've incorporated it into the script.

Answer (score 2):

**Save This Code As "ArtboardReplace.jsx" or Whatever You Like**

**And Go To File-Script-Other Scripts.. And Browse! Enjoy!**

```
//Replace "." with "_" Artboard illustrator script
#target illustrator
var doc = app.activeDocument;
for ( var i=0; i<doc.artboards.length ;i++) {
var aBoard = doc.artboards[i].active; // makes artboard active
var oldName = doc.artboards[i].name;
doc.artboards[i].name = oldName.replace (".", "_"); // replace . with _
}
```

Comment: That's a really great script, I would suggest - to allow it to receive input from the user when the script is run.

Comment: WELZ thanks For Doing it. since i was offline ;i was also thinking to do that but grats for doing it :)